# area tag in html

Tags: html

i have an image with 525 width. I need to place a link at the right side of the image. I know area tag is better to do this. But i don't know this tag. Could you please give me the coords attributes for this

Thanks

Comment: I'd personally `position: absolute` an `<a>` over the image, they're easier to style, position reliably and clearly indicate a click-able area to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area tag works as described here: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_area.asp. But why won't you use a CSS style to position the link absolute above the image?

```
<div>
  <img src="yadda.jpg" />
  <a href="#">blah</a>
</div>

div {
  position: relative;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```